# Sticky side-bar that scrolls with page when overflowing vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky side-panel containing several accordion elements that, when opened, cause the content of the panel to overflow past the bottom of the screen.

When that happens, I want to "unstick" the panel, allow it to scroll *with the rest of the page* (not with a separate scrollbar) until it reaches the bottom of it's content, at which point I'd like it to stick there. When the accordion that caused the overflow is closed, such that the content fits on the screen again, I want the panel to snap back to the top again.

I know I'm going to need to lean on a JS solution for this, and given that I'm already using bootstrap for my layout, I'm drawn to its Affix plugin, but the docs leave a lot to be desired.

So my question: Does Affix sound like an appropriate tool here - and if so, how could I use it to implement the behavior described above?

Comment: can you show your code or fiddle or screen?

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/ffymzm5e/)**

I made my answer in javascript and jquery.

What you want to do is create a function to find if the bottom or the top is visible:

```
//Is the bottom visible?
function bottomVissible(el) {
    var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.bottom <= $(window).height()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Is the top vissible?
function topVissible(el) {
    var rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Then we have to listen to events:

```
$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', handler);
```

We have to add a function that's called, on the event call. (we already set it to `handler`)

```
var handler = onVisibilityChange($('.side'));
```

And to tie it all together make a function for thats called on changes in the document and that adds that appropriate css value. I choose to go with css `margin-top`.

```
function onVisibilityChange(el) {
    return function () {
        if (bottomVissible(el)) {
            el.css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop() - el.outerHeight() + $(window).height());
        } else if (topVissible(el)) {
            el.css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop());
        }
    }
}
```